# Why am I getting segmentation fault and how to resolve it

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, segmentation-fault, binary-search

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int BSearch(int array[],int key,int left,int right)
{
    if(array[left+right/2]==key)
        cout<<left+right/2;
    else if(array[left+right/2]<key)
        BSearch(array,key,left,right/2-1);
    else 
        BSearch(array,key,right/2,right);

}

int main()
{
int list[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,15,21};
BSearch(list,5,0,sizeof(list)/sizeof(int)-1);
}
```

I wrote this program to perform binary search. I am getting Segmentation fault every time I run it.

Comment: You must add parenthesis: `(left+right)/2`

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı oh you probably commented while I was writing the answer. If you want, I can delete it, since it seems that you were here first.

Comment: @gsamaras Not necessary. :)

Comment: Please post **real** code. This does not even compile.

Comment: My answer was incomplete. Updated Sinha.

Comment: It's not incomplete. It's simply not legal C++. The code - as posted - does not compile (`BSearch` does not return a value). Please post **real** code.

Comment: Hmm @IInspectable I am not sure about that, maybe I debugged it myself, damn I must stop doing that!

Comment: @gsamaras: See [this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a642530c953f854): *"warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]"* I guess not everyone has *Treat warnings as errors* enabled. You should.

Comment: Well, after checking my answer I see that I have `void` as a return type, thus I debugged it, sorry you were right. Probably I did that to get rid of the warning but then forgot to mention it. Can I augment my answer with your comment @IInspectable? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be change less than to greater than in second if statement: `else if(array[(left+right)/2]>key)` because you search reverse side.

And you must change `right/2` to `(left+right)/2` in third if statement because left may not 0 and `right/2` will not corret. You must search from midle to riht side. Solution is

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int BSearch(int array[],int key,int left,int right)
{
    if(array[(left+right)/2]==key)
        cout<<(left+right)/2 << endl;
    else if(array[(left+right)/2]>key)
        BSearch(array,key,left,(left+right)/2-1);
    else 
        BSearch(array,key,(left+right)/2+1,right);
}

int main()
{
    int list[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,15,21};
    BSearch(list,5,0,sizeof(list)/sizeof(int)-1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check here:

```
if(array[left+right/2]==key)
```

and focus on this `left+right/2`. Here, the precedence of the operators comes into play. You probably meant add left and right and then divide the sum by two.

However, it will first divide right by two and then add that to left.

---

So change:

```
left+right/2
```

to:

```
(left+right)/2
```

*everywhere* you need to.

---

Moreover, your logic is flawed. I have already wrote an example in [Binary Search (C++)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/binary-search-c/), but even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) can help here. The code of yours works with this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void BSearch(int array[], int key, int left, int right) {
    if (array[(left + right) / 2] == key) {
        cout << "found at position " << (left + right) / 2;
        return;
    } else if (array[(left + right) / 2] > key) {
        BSearch(array, key, left, (left + right)/ 2 - 1);
    } else {
        BSearch(array, key,  (left + right)/ 2 + 1, right);
    }
}

int main() {
    int list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15, 21};
    BSearch(list, 5, 0, sizeof(list) / sizeof(int) - 1);
}
```

Output:

```
found at position 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the correct way of doing this is not

```
(left+right)/2
```

but

```
left + (right - left)/2
```

The difference is when working with large lists, the first variant has an overflow problem (undefined behavior with signed ints, not working as expected with unsigned).

Lets illustrate on the char type with range 0..255 unsigned and -128..127 signed (int just has a wider range but the problem remains).

Suppose you want to find a middle of signed chars 40 and 100:

- The result of the first expression [`(left+right)/2`] is: `(40+100)/2 = (-116)/2 = -58` (technically undefined, 40+100 char would only be -116 with the standard two's complement implementation but that is not mandated by the C/C++ standard)
- The result of the second [`left + (right - left)/2`] is `40 + (100-40)/2 = 40 + (60)/2 = 40 + 30 = 70`

With unsigned char 100 and 250:

- The first: `(100 + 250)/2 = (94)/2 = 47`
- The second: `100 + (250 - 100)/2 = 100 + 150 / 2 = 175`

For the recursive calls, you need to supply ranges along the "middle" point (again `L + (R-L)/2` instead of `R/2`).

In particular, as also mentioned in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm):

> Although the basic idea of binary search is comparatively
>   straightforward, the details can be surprisingly tricky… (Donald Knuth)

Comment: I understand that but I am still getting the same error, is anything else wrong too with the code.

Comment: That is because the subranges supplied to the recursive calls were wrong as well, as @gsamaras pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis issue discussed in the other answers is certainly a big issue, and must be fixed.  However, I don't think that is causing the segfault.

The first time `BSearch()` is called, `left` and `right` are 0 and 11, respectively.  5 is the (mistakenly) computed index, pointing to the value of 6.  As a result, the last line of `BSearch()` is called, passing 5 and 11 for `left` and `right`.

Following through the function again, the last line is called again, passing 5 and 11 again, **ad infinitum**.

You must correct how `BSearch()` computes the indexes to pass to itself.